# Is it possible to draw a regular expression in python to extract all string's attribute value

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, string

I have an xml file like this:

```
<string name="abc_searchview_description_clear">Clear query</string>
<string name="abc_searchview_description_query">Search query</string>
<string name="abc_searchview_description_search">Search</string>
<string name="abc_searchview_description_submit">Submit query</string>
<string name="abc_searchview_description_voice">Voice search</string>
<string name="abc_shareactionprovider_share_with">Share with</string>
```

and I want to find all the string values i.e., [Clear query, Search query, Search, Submit query, Voice search, Share with] in python3.

I'm just wondering if it is possible to draw regular expression for it? {similar to what we do to find all the text inside a double qoute [Find_double_quotes = re.compile('"([^"]*)"',re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)}

Answer (score 1):

If your use case is as simple as the one shown here (i.e. no nesting, no other tags), this should do it `re.findall("<string[^>]*>(.*)</string>", your_text)`

Although, XML is not a regular language, so the regex will fail for some more general cases. If you need it for more complex cases, you may consider not using regex for this.
See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/9951939) with a more detailed explanation.

Comment: And do remember that every time a recipient of XML writes code that can only handle a restricted subset of XML (e.g. XML with no comments in), some supplier of that XML is soon going to raise a question on StackOverflow asking how they can generate XML that conforms to that restricted subset. If this code is for live production use, then use a proper XML parser.

Answer (score 0):

Many Thanks, it works fine for me.

I also try this: 
Find_double_quotes = re.compile('">([^>]*)

It also produce the same result